# Reference error: "Workbook" is not defined

Tags: javascript, birt

I wanna use the next java script code:

```
function dumpVal(file) {
if (file !=null) {
var wb = new Workbook.create(file);
var sheet = wb.getSheet("Tabelle1");
for (myrow = 1; !isCellEmpty(sheet, myrow, 0); myrow++) {
dataset.setColumnValue("A",getNumericValue(sheet,myrow,0));
dataset.storeResultRow();
}
}
return;
}
```

but when I am compiling it I receive the next error message: `ReferenceError: "Workbook" is not defined.`
Can someone to tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the code which defines the object `Workbook`?

Comment: try like this-->  var wb = new Workbook().create(file);

Comment: @DeepakSharma — If `Workbook` isn't defined, then calling it as a function won't help. (And don't answer in the comments, use answers for answers).

Comment: I am assuming he include the excel library. () is a way to creating object. i am just asking him to try.

Comment: @DeepakSharma — `()` is not a way to create an object, it is a way to call a function. Since `Workbook` is `undefined`, it is not a function, so that won't work.

Comment: This looks like JavaScript designed to run in the presence of a particular library or inside something like Excel or Google Drive. Which is it? What documentation are you using to write this code? Did you skip a step? What JavaScript engine are you trying to run the code with?

Comment: with new keyword, you are going to create a object of workbook class. so it should be use like new Workbook();

Comment: @DeepakSharma — That only works if `Workbook` is a constructor function … which it is not … it is `undefined`.

Comment: @user — And how are you running that JS inside Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You recieve the error with the followig line of code:

```
var wb = new Workbook;
```

At the point where you create the workbook (new Workbook) you refer to a class called "Workbook". At this point your script dont have a class called Workbook it.

Solution: 
You should check your scripts if the class is included and its naming.
Maybe the class is initialized later!

For debug purposes you can try to create the class a line before:

```
class Workbook{ }
```

If you recieve an error now because Workbook needs a method called "create", you know that the class is just missing.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want to parse excel file from your web application, the library that you are using is for developing add-ins for excel not web application :

> **Excel JavaScript API programming overview**
>
> This article describes how to use the Excel JavaScript API to build add-ins for Excel 2016. It introduces key concepts that are fundamental to using the APIs, such as RequestContext, JavaScript proxy objects, sync(), Excel.run(), and load(). The code examples at the end of the article show you how to apply the concepts.
>
> **source :**
> https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview

If you want to parse Excel in your web application I suggest to use this library :

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

I did not use it so I cant garanty it, but you can look for similar librarys.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).